# how to use an incomplete list in its condition

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I know.. The title isn't explaining well..
 if you have a better title tell me in a comment..
I'm making a prime numbers generator for fun and learning purposes..
here's my code:

```
divisors x xs = [ y | y <- [1]++xs++[x], x `mod` y == 0]
isPrime x xs = divisors x xs == [1,x]
primeLst = [ x | x <- [2..], isPrime x primeLst]
```

As you can see.. I must use the already generated primes in a condition when generating a new one to reduce execution time..
 and it's not working..
 Is there a way of making it?

Comment: Hint: You only need to test for divisibility by primes up to the square root of the number, since any divisor greater than the square root is accompanied by one that's smaller than the square root.

Comment: thanks @hammar.. I'm planning to do that after solving this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start by looking at the `divisors` function. It is sort of correct, with only two issues:

1. What is the `xs` argument supposed to be? From the definition, it looks like it should be all the prime numbers below `x` - let's call these the candidate primes. So if `x` was `10`, then the candidate primes should be `[2,3,5,7]`. However, this is not what the function gets as an argument. In your code, `xs` is the infinite list of primes.
2. Technically, the `divisors` doesn't return all divisors. `divisors 16 [2,3,5,7,11,13]` wouldn't return `8`, for instance. But this is a minor nitpick.

So if we can call `divisors` with the right list of primes, then we should be ok, and the `isPrime` function would also be fine.

The problem is getting the list of candidate primes. For clarity, I will give the code first, and then explain:

```
primeLst = 2 : [ x | x <- [3..], isPrime x (takeWhile (\p -> p*p <= x) primeLst)]
```

I have made two changes:

1. I made sure that `primeLst` includes `2`, by sticking it at the front.
2. I restricted the candidate primes by taking numbers from the infinite list of primes until I reached a number that was higher than the square root of the number I was testing for primeness. In doing this i changed the definition of the candidate primes slightly, so for instance the candidates for `26` are `[2,3,5]` instead of `[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23]`. But it still works.

Two questions for you to think about:

1. Why does it still work with the new definition of candidate primes?
2. Why doesn't the following line of code work, even though it seems it should give the original definition of the candidate primes?

:

```
primeLst = 2 : [ x | x <- [3..], isPrime x (takeWhile (\p -> p < x) primeLst)]
```

The last question is hard, so if you have questions, post them in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications and time :D
Haskell is an interesting programming language..
and here are my answer:
1. because haskell is lazy, it will take only numbers from primeLst that their square root is less than x without calculating paying attention to other list elements..
2. because isPrime checks if the divisors are 1 and x
and in this code x isn't there I think replacing `p < x` by `p <= x`  may work..

Am I right?

Comment: euh.. there is an error.. `No instance for (Num [a0])
      arising from a use of 'isPrime'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [a0])
    In the expression: isPrime x (takeWhile (\ p -> p < x) primeLst)
    In a stmt of a list comprehension:
      isPrime x (takeWhile (\ p -> p < x) primeLst)
    In the second argument of '(:)', namely
      '[x | x <- [3 .. ], isPrime x (takeWhile (\ p -> p < x) primeLst)]'`
what's wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I don't get the error. I have those three lines that you have in your question, with the `primeLst` definition as I wrote it. Are you sure you have exactly the same? With no type annotations. Did it work with the first definition of `primeLst` I wrote?

Comment: The answer to the first question is given by hammar in his comment on your question. The square root of 14 is between 3 and 4, so it doesn't matter if the candidate primes are `[2,3]` or `[2,3,5,7,11,13]`, because even though 7 divides 14, 7 has a pair (which is 2) below the square root that also divides 14. So you don't need to include numbers higher than the square root in the candidate primes, because they would be paired with a number below the square root, which would be included in the reduced candidate primes.

Comment: The second question: The difference between the two versions is that `takeWhile (\p -> p*p <= x) primeLst` means take primes until you reach a number thats higher than the square root of `x`, while `takeWhile (\p -> p < x) primeLst` means take primes until you reach a prime that is equal to `x` or higher. If you go with the first definition, then the first prime is 2. after that you check 3. The square root of 3 is between 1 and 2, so when you reach 2 in the `takeWhile`, you can stop there. 3 gets added. Then you check 4, and reach 3, which is now in the list, and above the square root of 4.

Comment: cont: In this way, you always meet a number in the `primeLst` that is higher than the square root of the number you are checking. If you choose the second definition, then you have to take primes until you reach a number that is equal or higher than `x`. So when you check 3, you can take the 2 that is in the `primeLst`, but after that we haven't found any other primes. We are checking 3, but we don't know if it is prime yet. So the computation is stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I rechecked and your code works perfectly!
I still have 2 questions.
1- which is faster: this way or Sergey's?
2- my complete code is:
`import System.IO
divisors x xs = [ y | y <- [1]++xs++[x], x `mod` y == 0]
isPrime x xs = divisors x xs == [1,x]
primeLst = 2 : [ x | x <- [3..], isPrime x (takeWhile (\p -> p*p <= x) primeLst)]
write h = mapM_ (\(a,b) -> hPrint h ("["++show a++"] => "++show b))
main = do
 withFile "primes.txt" ReadWriteMode (\handle -> do
  write handle (zip [1..] (take 500000 primeLst)))
`
the output is: "[1] => 2"
"[2] => 3"...
how to remove ""?

Comment: @IderAghbal: Use `hPutStrLn` instead of `hPrint`. The latter calls `show` to format the result like a Haskell value, so strings get quotes etc. `hPutStrLn` writes the string directly.

Comment: @IderAghbal: This code (with `takeWhile (\p -> p*p <= x) primeLst`) is almost the same as Sergey's. In your `divisors` function you append `1` and `x` to the candidate primes, and `isPrime` then checks to see, if they are the only ones returned. This is the same as saying that none of the candidate primes divide `x`. This is what Sergey does. In his verbose listing, `isPrime` is defined as `null $ primeDivisors x`. This is a little faster, because `null` can terminate early, if `primeDivisors x` has at least 1 element. So if `x` is 50, and  `primeDivisors x` is `[2,3,5,7]`, `null` can

Comment: @IderAghbal: cont: return `False` as soon as it realizes that `primeDivisors x` contains 2. It doesn't have to check all the values. This is because of laziness, which can be summarized as: only compute as much as needed to get the answer you need. And because of this, Sergey's code is faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
dividedBy a b = a `mod` b == 0
isPrime x = null $ filter (x `dividedBy`) $ takeWhile (\y -> y * y <= x) primeLst
primeLst = 2:(filter isPrime [3..])
```

or, more verbose:

```
primeLst = 2:(filter isPrime [3..])
  where
    isPrime x = null $ primeDivisors x
    primeDivisors x = filter (x `dividedBy`) $ potentialDivisors x
    potentialDivisors x = takeWhile (\y -> y * y <= x) primeLst
    a `dividedBy` b = a `mod` b == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculating at least one element of `primeLst` requires calculating `isPrime 2 primeLst` which requires calculating at least two elements of `divisors 2 primeLst` which requires calculating at least two elements of `[1]++primeLst++[2]`, which requires calculating at least one element of `primeLst`.  Not gonna happen.

You might be able to make something work that uses `[1]++(primesLessThan x)++[x]`, but I don't see a straightforward way to define `(primesLessThan x)` in terms of `primeLst` which avoids computational circularity.

Comment: then I will modify my code in this way: `primeLst = [2]++[ x | x <- [2..], isPrime x primeLst]` .. But this doesn't work..